# Use Adobe TypeKit fonts in an SVG object embedded in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, webfonts

How can I use fonts from Adobe TypeKit in an SVG object embedded in an HTML page?

I'm able to use web fonts directly (e.g. via a google stylesheet: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spicy+Rice), but TypeKit uses a different javascript-based loading strategy which doesn't seem to be applying font availability to the SVG object.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted the typekit maintainers?

Comment: Nope, not yet. I did find a hackish workaround though; you can just grab the stylesheet from the html DOM after it loads and then apply it to the SVG. One of the better fixes would probably be for TypeKit to add support for running their script directly from the SVG file.

Comment: I asked Typekit/Adobe and they said that they hadn't done much testing with SVG files, but noted my request for such support.

Comment: How did you apply the stylesheet from the html DOM and apply it to the SVG?

Comment: @AndrewSwift - I think you have to reference it from within the SVG, via something like <xhtml:link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>. If you wanted to decouple the stylesheet, you could append the element to the SVG, after it's loaded, via javascript .

Comment: I wrote a Jquery plugin for internal use that converts an <img src="*.svg"> to an object and injects the Typekit stylesheet from the parent document so you can reuse the fonts inside this SVG: https://github.com/willemvb/svg-typekit

Answer (score 2):

SVG is stylable with CSS stylesheets, so you should be able to apply it that way.

And as long as the font is registered on the page, you can use `textElToApplyFontTo.attr({ "font-family": "myFont" });`

Note that IE<9 will likely have problems, I don't know much about VML font support. IE9+ has SVG support, so it should work with that, and all other modern [desktop] browsers.

One important thing to consider is that Typekit and other JS-based loading mechanisms work asynchronously, so fonts will only be available once they're loaded.

Some modern browsers won't load the font unless a DOM element is using it, so that may also be causing problems (you can try to load the font by using it on a DOM element, preferably above the SVG file. A dirty trick but it works...).

Comment: I don't downvote answers, but this is not correct. CSS rules do not cascade into `<object>` elements. Those are completely opaque to CSS rules. CSS rules only apply to inline SVG.

Comment: I didn't mean you could use the same CSS rules for both the HTML and SVG. I was suggesting a means for loading fonts faster and making them available to the SVG object. I apologize for the misunderstanding. Thanks for not downvoting my answer.

Comment: Cool. The answer makes perfect sense now.